# how to properly implement single sign in inside ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a single sign on inside ionic app; such that when a user sign in the first time except he signs out, he should have a direct access to the app without having to sign in multiple times.

The implementation works only that before a user is directed to the app page, he sees, the splash screen briefly, then the login page briefly and finally the right page i want him to see upon app lunch.

I have a service called `UserService` that saves the user data to local storage upon the first login.

Then I did a check if data exists in the UserService, if yes, take users to the app page, otherwise follow the normal process of login. This was done in the run inside the `app.js` like this

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $state, UserService,localStorage) 
{
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)

        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) 
        {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if(window.StatusBar) 
        {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        // implement single sign on here
        user = UserService.getUser().loggedInUserId;
        if(user !==undefined  )
        {
            console.log("user exists")
            $state.go('app.apppage');
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("user does not exist")
        }
    })
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you found the solution yet, coz I'm also looking to apply a one time login system by which user login once and keep on using the app until he/she logged out. ~Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by handling splashscreen through code.

Add splashscreen plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git
```

Disable AutoHideSplashScreen property in config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Then modify tour code like below,

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $state, UserService,localStorage, $timeout) 
{
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)

        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) 
        {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if(window.StatusBar) 
        {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

        // implement single sign on here
        user = UserService.getUser().loggedInUserId;
        if(user !==undefined  )
        {
            console.log("user exists")
            $state.go('app.apppage');
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("user does not exist")
        }

        //====================
        //  hide splash screen
        //====================

        $timeout(function() {
          // clear history to prevent the user from navigating back to login page
          $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
          navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 1000);

        //=======================

    })
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's better to hide the splashscreen in the if statement, instead of the timeout making the login quicker if it takes less than a second.

Comment: @pcagica But user will be seeing the page transition if we hide splashscreen immediately instead if we use timeout user will be landed in the target page.

Comment: @subash Selvaraj, it's close to what I want, but if you hit the back button, one still see the login page

Comment: It's true what you say,  but normally de transitions duration are 400ms, less for IOS.  I was just saying that you could make it quicker,  but it's a matter of configuration until you don't see the transition.

Comment: and when you remove the app from the running app, it shows the cordova splashscreen, with a loading animation, this continue perpetually, but one quits that and try to lunch the app again, it goes straight to the desired page

Comment: @kplus, with respect to back button issue, you can use $ionicHistory.clearHistory(). I have updated my code

Comment: I am not able to get the issue with respect to your second mentioned issue.

Comment: @Subash Selveraj, Thanks, you are aware I am building for android platform right?

Comment: How about the Security? Is it secure to store logged in user credentials (like token or username/password) into the localStorage? I assumed its not. Comment please.

Comment: @RiteshAryal storage is your preference. Not necessarily to be localStorage you can leverage sqlite or whatever. Also, if you are creating mobile app using ionic, it is not a harm to store in localStorage since localStorage is not shared accross all webviews if I am not wrong. Share your thoughts.